# Copy and combine data from 2 different source to 1 destination in C++

Tags: c++, stdvector, memcpy

How do I copy and combile data from 2 different source to 1 destination in C++?

```
struct M{
   int a;
   int b;
}m;

struct N{
   int c;
   int d;
}n;
std::vector<std::uint8_t> destination(sizeof(M)+sizeof(N));
memcpy(destination.data(), ?? , sizeof(M)+sizeof(N))
```

How do I combile the M and N and add it in to the 2nd parameter in the memcpy function? appreciate some help
thank you

Comment: Two `memcpy` calls? Keep in mind that this completely ignores alignment restrictions that may be imposed on the members of M or N.

Comment: Use 2 `memcpy`s (1 for each struct) with a proper offset into the `vector`.

Comment: @Botje Alignment is irrelevant for copying data into a byte array (or, more accurately: `alignof(std::uint8_t) == 1`, and the alignment of the source data members does not come into play).

Answer (score 3):

You cannot use [`memcpy`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/memcpy) to copy data from 2 different sources (in 1 call).
But you can call it twice - once for each source.

Note that the second copy should take into account that the first source already occupies the beginning of the buffer:

```
std::vector<std::uint8_t> destination(sizeof(M) + sizeof(N));
std::memcpy(destination.data(), &m, sizeof(M));
//-----------------------------vvvvvvvvvv------------------
std::memcpy(destination.data() + sizeof(M), &n, sizeof(N));
```